# What does validate() function do in flask wtf

Tags: python, flask-wtforms

Does the `validate()` function in `flask wtforms` validate the entire fields in the form, or only those fields to which validators have been applied?

Comment: please, try to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Here's the implementation of form.validate() taken for wtforms:

```
def validate(self, extra_validators=None):
    self._errors = None
    success = True
    for name, field in iteritems(self._fields):
        if extra_validators is not None and name in extra_validators:
            extra = extra_validators[name]
        else:
            extra = tuple()
        if not field.validate(self, extra):
            success = False
    return success
```

You can see that it validate each field of the form using it associated validators + extra_validators given.